# Add dynamic form fields and validations to formArray in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to build a dynamic form, where the field names and their validations will come from an API

so I'm creating a simple form, with a formArray inside, something like this:

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  dynamicFields: this.formBuilder.array([])  // where I will be pushing the custom fields and their validations
});
```

Just for testing, I'm trying to add a field 'country', with 2 validations (required, minLength of 22)

this is what I'm doing:

```
let customControl = this.fb.control('country', [ Validators.required, Validators.min(10) ]);
(this.myForm.get('dynamicFields') as FormArray).push(customControl);
```

I also created the bellow getter to use it in my template

```
getDynFields() {
  return this.myForm.get('dynamicFields') as FormArray;
}
```

and this is the template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formArrayName="dynamicFields">
    <div *ngFor="let control of getDynFields().controls; let i = index">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input
          [formControlName]="i"
          matInput
          type="text"
          placeholder="{{ control.value }}"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

what is happening (as you see below) is that for the field value and placeholder I'm getting 'country' pre-populated (I only want the placeholder to be 'country' and the value should be empty of course)
And the second issue is that **only required validation is working,** minLength is not doing anything

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want async validator to check uniqness name or something I recomended this link: https://medium.com/@tomaszsochacki/how-to-do-asynchronous-validator-in-angular-7-6e80243a874a - nice and simple example. And if you use material check the tag `<mat-error>` .
Secondly you should replace `min()` with `minLength()`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. 

On a sidenote: Please try to ask a single question. Asking two will get you half-answers . It could even be a reason to close your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormControl takes `'state'` or default value as first param while initialising. Also for min length, you should use `Validators.minLength(n)`.

```
constructor(formState: any = null, validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | AbstractControlOptions | ValidatorFn[], asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[])
```

instead of this

```
let customControl = this.fb.control('country', [ Validators.required, Validators.min(10) ]);
```

you should do this

```
let customControl = this.fb.control('', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10) ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Validators.min() vs Valiadators.minLength()**

You are using [Validators.min()](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#min). This is intented to check numerical input values, not to get the length of a string:

```
let customControl = this.fb.control('country', [ Validators.required, Validators.min(10) ]);
```

Use [Validators.minLength()](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#minlength) instead:

```
let customControl = this.fb.control('country', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10) ]);
```

**The first parameter of a FormControl is its value**

[The first parameter of a FormControl is its value](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#constructor()). You are setting a value of 'country' in your example:

```
let customControl = this.fb.control('country', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10) ]);
```

If you set it to null you will see whatever placeholder you have set.

```
let customControl = this.fb.control(null, [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10) ]);
```

You can implement the placeholder however you want in your template. As a string or a reference to some objects property.

Answer (score 0):

For min length please use Validators.minLength(22) 
Please refer: https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#minLength for more info.
min(10) used to add validation as minimum value can be 10.